# sqlplus spool in a different files

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

i have 2 selects and i need it to be moved in a 2 different files:
example:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET LINESIZE 4000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SPOOL SAP.CSV

DECLARE
  lRecordCount  NUMBER(10) := 2;
  lRecordCount2 NUMBER(10) := 2;
BEGIN

  FOR t IN (SELECT distinct c.customerno line
              FROM customer c
             WHERE c.status = 1
               and c.type = 2
               and c.customerno like '2%'
               and rownum <= 150)

   LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(t.line);
    lRecordCount := lRecordCount + 1;
  END LOOP;


  FOR t2 IN (SELECT distinct i.invoiceno line
               FROM invoice i
              WHERE i.amount > 0
                and i.invoiceno is not null
                and rownum <= 150
                and i.invoiceno like '295%')

   LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(t2.line);
    lRecordCount2 := lRecordCount2 + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
SPOOL OFF
EXIT
```

i need that results from "t" and "t2" were recorded to two different files:SAP.CSV, INV.CSV

is it possible for sqlplus and how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put your FOR loops in two different anonymous blocks, then do a `SPOOL OFF` followed by `SPOOL INV.CSV` between them.  The first should go to one file and the second to the other.